# NLP(natural language processing) How to detect question with any method?

Tags: nlp

I search a machine learning method detecting some question.

Example,

```
 User: Please tell me your name ?     
 AI  : (AI find User want to know his name)   
       My name is [AI's name].
```

My dataset is as follows.

```
[label], [question]    
   1   , What's your name?    
   1   , Tell me your name.
   ...
```

But the problem is to include something that is not a question in the input.

Example,

```
User: Hello, my name is [User name]
AI  : (this is not a question)    
      (throw another process)
      (->) Nice to meet you.
```

The number of Question's categories is 10~20, but the number of sentences which is not a question is too many.

Do you know how to solve this question Or any task related to this?

Comment: So to clarify, your dataset has a set of question, label pairs, and you want a system that, given an unseen question, will identify the category it most likely belongs to *or* indicate when it doesn't think a question belongs to any of the categories?

Comment: I can not envision details in detail, but in my opinion, threathold > argmax(questions's related)... (if argmax is smaller than threathold, it is not a question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to factor the problem into three parts.

- First, you'll want to map the arbitrary-length sequence of text onto a fixed-length vector. For this, you might look at [Le and Mikolov's "Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents"](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf)
- Once you have that, the problem reduces to a simple classification task.  You have a set of vectors and the categories each maps to. A network with one hidden layer and a softmax output layer should probably be sufficient.  This will give you a distribution over categories.
- Finally, you need to determine a confidence level for each prediction.  There are two broad approaches that come to mind.

  1. First, you can introduce a new category for "miscellaneous", and add any sentences that don't fit into one of the "real" categories to it.  The weakness of this approach is that this class is actually the union of many unrelated classes and thus might be difficult to learn, since the points will be scattered all over the paragraph vector space rather than existing in a nice cluster.
  2. Alternately, you might look at the values of the output neurons *before* you normalize using softmax, and output "unknown category" if the value for the most likely category doesn't exceed some threshold.  You'll probably want to tune the threshold value to maximize accuracy over a validation set.

I can't guarantee that this will work, but it's the approach I would try first.

Comment: Thanks to your information.　　　　
I am worried that the difference in the number of samples for each category will increase. I am worried that sentences that are not questions are overwhelmingly more than sentences that are questions...
Anyway, I will experiment.

Comment: @TakuyaEbata If there are that many out-of-class examples, you might switch the order of the last two steps: first, have a network that just gives the probability that it belongs to *any* of the classes, and then a second network that identifies which class it belongs to and is *only* trained on the ones that belong to one of them.